# string length with fgets function in C

Tags: c, c-strings, fgets, strlen

I have a problem. I've tried to see the length of some string after using fgets function. If I enter string under the number of letter which can be in the string (like: the maximum letters in string is 9 and I enter 4 letters), I get length of the string+1. why?

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char name[10]={0};
    printf("enter your name\n");
    fgets(name, 10, stdin);
    printf("your name is %s and it is %d letters\n", name, strlen(name)); // length problem 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What about the man-page of `fgets` is unclear? Did you inspect the array after the function in your debugger? What did you find at the end of the string?

Comment: `fgets()` includes the newline in the input — if it reads the newline.

Comment: ...and after the name your output moves to **next line**...

Comment: `strlen` return `size_t` so use `%zu` as format specifier

Comment: Look closely at what your code prints and you will see a line break after the four letters you entered had been printed. This new-line is the 5th element: `\n`.

Comment: "I enter 4 letters" --> Hint: you typed 5 keys.

Comment: `fgets` also returns `NULL` on failure, which you are not checking.

Answer (score 5):

From fgets manual page (https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets):

> fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and
>   stores them into the buffer pointed to by s. Reading stops after an
>   EOF or a newline. If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.
>   A terminating null byte (aq\0aq) is stored after the last character in
>   the buffer.

So it adds `'\n'` after your 4 letters, returning `string_length+1`.

From [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input) you can add @Tim Čas solution to your code.

The line is still read with the `fgets()` function and after we remove the newline character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(void)
{
    char name[10] = { 0 };
    printf("enter your name\n");
    fgets(name, 10, stdin);
    printf("your name is %s and it is %d letters\n", name, strlen(name)); // length problem 
    name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = 0;
    printf("NEW - your name is %s and it is %d letters\n", name, strlen(name));
    return 0;
}
```

That outputs:

```
enter your name
Andy
your name is Andy
 and it is 5 letters
NEW - your name is Andy and it is 4 letters
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: so how can I get the string without the new line that it adds (delete the `'\n' if the function adds it?)

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Comment: See [@LPs  %zu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41572713/string-length-with-fgets-function-in-c#comment70350205_41572713)

Answer (score 3):

If a character array has enough space then the standard function `fgets` also includes the new line character `'\n'` in the array that usually corresponds to the pressed key Enter.

You can remove this redundant new line character the following way

```
name[strcspn( name, "\n" )] = '\0';
```

after that you will get the expected result of applying the function `strlen`.

Answer (score 2):

Because the end of line character `'\n'` is included in the string copied into `name` by `fgets()` .

Answer (score 1):

As is written in `man fgets`,

> The fgets() function reads at most one less than the number of characters
>        specified by size from the given stream and stores them in the string
>        str.  Reading stops when a newline character is found, at end-of-file or
>        error.  The newline, if any, is retained.  If any characters are read and
>        there is no error, a `\0' character is appended to end the string.

Since you are reading from `stdin`, `fgets(name, 10, stdin)` reads at most 9 characters from stdin buffer and appends `\0` to the end. It just happens that the new line character `\n` produced when user hit enter is in the buffer too.

As a sidenote, it is customary (and a good practice) to use `sizeof()` when specifying size of the array passed to `fgets`.

```
fgets(name, (int) sizeof(name), stdin);
```

Comment: "*It can never go wrong!*" sure, as its a machine, but it still can be *used* wrongly. Imaging using as pointer instead of an array: `char * readstr(char * p) { return fgets(p, sizeof p, stdin); }` would (on most systems) try to read 4 or 8 `char`s.

Comment: "It can never go wrong!"  --> note that `sizeof` returns type `size_t`, yet `fgets(char * s, int n, FILE *  stream)` uses an `int` for the size.  With huge arrays, this may convert unexpectantly.  Certainly rare, but not _never_.

Comment: How do you know it can never go wrong if you don't check it's return value? `fgets` can return `NULL` from `stdin` if `EOF` is encountered.

Comment: I am merely suggesting OP to pass sizeof(name) instead of 10 to `fgets`. It can always go wrong when things are taken out of context. Thanks for the comments. updated the answer.

Comment: @PejmanGh I'm sorry if I sounded rude. Up vote from me :).